# How to add/change a value of $wpdb property/var?

Tags: links, wpdb

There is a problem: I want to add a table 'linkmeta' to work like 'postmeta' or 'commentmeta'.. and use functions like add_metadata / [update_metadata](http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/wp-includes/meta.php.source.html#l98) / delete_metadata!

but, in this functions call "_get_meta_table()" to verify the name in db, this code:

```
function _get_meta_table($type) {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $type . 'meta';
    if ( empty($wpdb->$table_name) )
        return false;
    return $wpdb->$table_name;
}
```

so, if doesn't exist the property/var named 'linkmeta' in $wpdb, `_get_meta_table` will return false, then `update_metadata` too will not work, because this piece of code at begin of that:

```
if ( ! $table = _get_meta_table($meta_type) )
    return false;
```

but, if I can set a property/var of (class) `$wpdb` like `$wpdb->linkmeta` return the correct name of table, in this case (default) wp_linkmeta, all the rest will work NICE!

so, there is a way to change wpdb in runtime?
if I just put the commands:

```
$wpdb->tables = array_merge($wpdb->tables, array('linkmeta'));
$wpdb->linkmeta = $wpdb->prefix . 'linkmeta';
```

at plugin initialize, will it work when function `_get_meta_table` is called??!

rgds

Comment: I was searching for an answer to this problem as well, with no luck, so I really hope, someone can answer it.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, just declare global `$wpdb` early enough and modify its fields. Codex docs for [`add_metadata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_metadata) say exactly that:

> Note that you will also have to register the table with the $wpdb object in order for it to work. Simply add the following to WordPress' init hook (or at least before you attempt to use any custom metadata functions).
>
> ```
> global $wpdb;
> $wpdb->termmeta = $wpdb->prefix.'termmeta';
> ```